# Why does my code print the pattern in different places when I repeat the pattern?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

It always prints the snowman in different places when you repeat the pattern, it’s just the body of the snowman that is all over the place but the eyes, buttons etc. are correct. I think it’ because the circles that make up the body are different sizes and it prints diagonally. Please help thanks so much.

```
# Import required module 
import turtle 
  
# Create turtle object 
t = turtle.Turtle() 
  
# Create a screen  
screen =turtle.Screen() 
  
# Set background color 
screen.bgcolor("sky blue") 
      
# Function to draw body of snowman 
def draw_circle(color, radius, x, y):
    t.penup() 
    t.fillcolor (color) 
    t.goto (x, y) 
    t.pendown() 
    t.begin_fill() 
    t.circle (radius) 
    t.end_fill() 

# Function to draw arms  
def create_line(x, y, length, angle): 
    t.penup() 
    t.goto(x, y) 
    t.setheading(angle) 
    t.pendown() 
    t.forward(length) 
    t.setheading(angle + 20) 
    t.forward(20) 
    t.penup() 
    t.back(20)
    t.pendown() 
    t.setheading(angle - 20) 
    t.forward(20) 
    t.penup() 
    t.home() 

# Illustrating snowman  
# Drawing snowman body 
def snowman(x):
    t.pensize(3)
    draw_circle ("#ffffff", 30 , 0 + x*100, -40) 
    draw_circle ("#ffffff", 40 , 0 + x*100, -100) 
    draw_circle ("#ffffff", 60 , 0 + x*100, -200) 
    # Drawing left eye 
    draw_circle ("#ffffff", 2 , -10 + x*100, -10)  
    # Drawing right eye 
    draw_circle ("#ffffff", 2 , 10 + x*100, -10)  
    # Drawing nose 
    draw_circle ("#FF6600", 3 , 0 + x*100, -15)  
    # Drawing buttons on 
    draw_circle ("#ffffff", 2 , 0 + x*100, -35) 
    draw_circle ("#ffffff", 2 , 0 + x*100, -45) 
    draw_circle ("#ffffff", 2 , 0 + x*100, -55) 
    # Drawing left arm 
    create_line(-35 + x*100, -50, 30, 160)  
    # Drawing right arm 
    create_line(35 + x*100, -50, 30, 20)  
    # Drawing hat 
    t.penup() 
    t.goto (-35 + x*100, 8) 
    t.color ("black") 
    t.pensize (6) 
    t.pendown() 
    t.goto (35 + x*100, 8) 
    t.goto (30 + x*100, 8) 
    t.fillcolor ("black") 
    t.begin_fill() 
    t.left (90) 
    t.forward (15) 
    t.left (90) 
    t.forward (60) 
    t.left (90) 
    t.forward (15) 
    t.end_fill()

repeat = int(input("how many times would you like to repeat the pattern?"))

def penPattern():
    for x in range (repeat):
        snowman(x)
        
penPattern()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your turtle is facing a different direction when beginning the first snowman, compared to the direction when beginning the second snowmen.

For the first snowmen, your turtle is facing right when beginning to draw each ball. This will make the starting position you pass to `draw_circle` the bottom-most point of the circle. For the second snowman, your turtle is facing down. This will make the starting position you pass to `draw_circle` the left-most point of the circle. See the starting positions and directions indicated here:

[image]

To fix this, you should restore the turtle direction to face right after finishing the first snowman. You can do this by adding `t.left (90)` to the end of your `snowman` function:

[image]